# Position from adapters onBindViewHolder doesn't get show in toast

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I'm trying to print the position from `onBindViewHolder`, but my toast is blank.

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
....
holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ....
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

all this is in the end being printed in a toast in my `MainActivity`

```java
String pos = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
Toast.makeText(this, pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I can't seem to find the issue, on how to get the position value of the `onBindViewHolder` function.

Comment: why you don't use position directly instead of pos ??

Comment: Where are you calling this toast in your main activity? Is it in onCreate()? If so, try to do it in onResume() method. Don't forget to check getIntent() for null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this way your code

```
String pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0).toString();
Toast.makeText(this, pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any other child view of this same parent could be accessible from v.

I have EditText & Button in a row, when I click on button below code will give you value of EditText to pass to another Activity. By this way I can send **id** of the row.

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout)v.getParent();
intent.putExtra("editTextValue", ((EditText)layout.getChildAt(0)).getText());
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change position to string value by one line of code -

```
intent.putExtra("position", position+"");
```